# how to validate Paramter id and token Claim Id are same from Authorize tag

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, basic-authentication

is there any way to validate parameter value and my token value are same or not.. from Authorize Tag

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "abc", Roles = "Parents", Policy = "ParentsOnly")]
```

example: `public async Task<IActionResult> GetParentInfoAsync(int parentId) { }`

my JWT token generated from ParentId 221   and  i pass in parameter 225 id .. its work fine parameter id compare my custom claim method... but how to authorize tag auto validate this is not a correct parentId

and if its not possible i want to get parameter value from below method.in request.Path i am getting full url.. but i want only paramter value and controller name any idea how to get this

```
 protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync(){
var requestvalue = Request.Path;
}
```

Startup.cs

```
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("ParentOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Sid));
                });
```

in ClaimTypes.Sid  my ParentId

Comment: This is exactly what policies are for, and you already apparently have a `ParentsOnly` policy. What is your exact issue? What is not working?

Comment: @ChrisPratt  i edit my question add startup.cs policy ...  but can you explain what is missing ..?